# jQuery click / on(click) event does not fire in Firefox?

Tags: jquery, events, onclick, jquery-events

Following code: one click event (close login box) does not fire in Firefox (webkit-browser work, however. And also the `slideToggle` click event works in all browsers). Does anybody have any ideas why?

### HTML

```
<div class="loginbox" id="loginbox">
    <div class="loginbox_close" id="loginbox_close"></div>
    ...
    <input type="button" value="Login" class="btn_login"></div>
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#menu').on('click', '#menu_login', function() {
            alert('test'); // this DOES fire, works in all browsers
        $('#loginbox').slideToggle(240,'swing');
    });
    $('#loginbox').on('click', '#loginbox_close', function() {
        alert('test'); // does not fire in FF, however webkit browser work!
        $('#loginbox').slideUp(240,'swing');
    });
});
```

### CSS

```
.loginbox {
    width:164px;
    padding:10px 18px 14px 18px;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    border-top:0px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:780px;
    background:#678;
    opacity:0.9;
    box-shadow:inset 20px 40px 80px 4px #789,0 2px 8px #ABC;
    }

.loginbox_close {
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    float:right;
    background:#EEE;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:150px;
    }
```

Comment: which height has the loginbox? is it display:block or inline?

Comment: @Daniel Ruf: this is the whole css, so there is no height defined... before I had a min-height, however then the slideToggle event stopped for some milliseconds at that point...

Comment: @DanielRuf: thx anyway, interesting point... I tried to add a height attribute, but unfortunately it did not change anything... so, same results..

Comment: did you try to put that code at the end of the file?

Comment: @DanielRuf: Jamie's answer solved it, thx anyway Daniel! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're using a delegated event the click will only fire when bubbled up from `#loginbox_close`.

[Here's a working example of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/FMtuk/) with the `#loginbox_close` outlined in red. Click this box and you'll see the event working.

And [here's a fuller version](http://jsfiddle.net/FMtuk/1/) using your code directly from above with the red border added also.

Comment: thank you Jamie, for your answer and effort! I am really sorry, but I have no idea what this means... it sounds great what you say but I'm afraid I completely don't get it... sorry..

Comment: The second parameter that you're passing to the `on` function is the id of an element. This tells the click event to only fire if the event that's attached to `#loginbox` came as a result of clicking on `#loginbox_close`.

Comment: looks for me like the original code? but a </div> was too much?

Comment: The code is exactly the same @DanielRuf except for the border I put on the `#loginbox_close`. Not sure what you mean by `</div>`.

Comment: i mean the </div> behind the <input>  seems this was the problem

Answer (score 0):

You better use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu_login').click(function() {
        alert('test'); // this DOES fire, works in all browsers
        $('#loginbox').slideToggle(240,'swing');
    });
    $('#loginbox_close').click(function() {
        alert('test'); // does not fire in FF, however webkit browser work!
        $('#loginbox').slideUp(240,'swing');
    });
});
```

It should work. With this you're assigning the click event directly to the menu_login and loginbox divs.

Comment: thank you ABottoni for this, I have tried click directly, however it does not work either in this place... furthermore I need to use .on, as later at some points the log inbox is being loaded via jquery ajax and click won't work then...

Answer (score 0):

If the login box is loaded using ajax you can use:

```
$('#loginbox_close').live('click',function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: thx Iddo for your answer, `.on` does the same here as `.live`, however there are some disadvantages of `.live` (there was a great blog called sth like "everything live has to die"), but I don't have a link anymore unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

seems the `</div>` behind the input is too much, delete it.

```
<div class="loginbox" id="loginbox">
<div class="loginbox_close" id="loginbox_close"></div>
...
<input type="button" value="Login" class="btn_login">
</div>
```

Comment: the what behind the input? do you mean the id of the button? why do you think it is too much?

Comment: ah, very sharp eye! :) it was my fault, I left out the unnecessary html elements in between (as shown with the `...`), so the opening `<div>` is there in the dots... but you could not know that, it was my mistake (copy paste)